# swipe or scroll to bottom in appium - android

Tags: android, selenium, appium

How can I swipe scroll to bottom in an android app using `appium`?
I tried using

```
driver.swipe(300,800,300,500,2);
driver.scrollTo("string")
```

But above did not helped. Can anyone suggest me some generic solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic solution will be scrolling using dimensions. use the below code

```
 public void scroll() throws IOException {
                  try {
                    Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
                    System.out.println("Size of screen= " +dimensions);
                    int Startpoint = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5);
                    System.out.println("Size of scrollStart= " +Startpoint );
                    int scrollEnd = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2);
                    System.out.println("Size of cscrollEnd= " + scrollEnd);             
                    driver.swipe(0, Startpoint,0,scrollEnd,1000);           

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }    
          }
```

add this to ur code and simply use scroll(); in ur test case. Modify the decimal values given in the code to nmeet your requirements

Comment: This is not scrolling the screen to bottom. :(

Comment: modify the values of parameters in driver.swipe(0, Startpoint,0,scrollEnd,1000);

Comment: I modified them.. It is getting screen size but it does not scroll on phone.

Comment: I checked, it runs in debug mode but running program, its failing.